# Contributions redirecting to the home page

Tags: wordpress, contributions

Having a strange issue with membership contributions. The contribution goes through, membership created as is organisation and individual contact, but instead of showing the thank you page it 302 redirects to the home page.

Any idea what could cause this?

We're on Wordpress 6.0.1 and Civi 5.46.3

Comment: This happens when there is an error when recording Contribution or any other entity. Check CiviCRM log for errors

Comment: Are you using Clean URLs? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/clean-urls/