# Permission denied error for thank you pages

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

No one can view the thank you pages following a contribution.  This was working a few days ago ... we had a donation page that granted access to a section of the website and the only way the user could get the URL of the protected pages was in the thank you page and their reciept.

Now, none of the thank you pages are working.  They just go back to the form and the error log is below.  Note that the payment goes through and the emailed receipt is sent, but the page just refreshes back to the form with a url that looks like https://example.org/donate/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&_qf_Main_display=true&qfKey=CRMContributeControllerContribution1qyg4ncbkp40g00gsso4s0c4woggggw8kwcs0kgk4gsck444co_787

```
Oct 19 16:21:29  [info] Contribution 1284 updated successfully

Oct 19 16:21:31  [info] Contribution 1284 Receipt sent

Oct 19 16:21:42  [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "You do not have permission to access this page."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#5547
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "You do not have permission to access this page."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php"
    #line: 615
    trace: {
      /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:615 {
        ›   $civicrm_wp_title = ts('You do not have permission to access this page.');
        ›   throw new CRM_Core_Exception(ts('You do not have permission to access this page.'));
        › }
      }
      /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php:62 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:239 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php:380 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:307 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:331 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:524 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:787 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1330 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:16 { …}
      /home/example/public_html/index.php:17 { …}
    }
  }
]


Oct 19 16:21:42  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(380): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#4 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))
#5 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))
#6 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(524): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#7 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(787): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#8 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1330): WP->main("")
#9 /home/example/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#10 /home/example/public_html/index.php(17): require("/home/example/public_html/wp-blog-header.php")
#11 {main}
```

This was for an donation by an admin, and I just can't figure out why this is happening.

Wordpress 6.0.3
CiviCRM 5.53.0

Any pointers are appreciated!!

Comment: feel like i have seen this recently posted by someone else. may be worth re-searching

Comment: maybe this one? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42526/contributions-redirecting-to-the-home-page

Comment: Yes, I checked that one, and many others.  I do have clean URL's enabled.  This was a sudden change, though.  I did my last update two weeks ago and I know it was working then.